# Карточки как в Steam

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

В десктопной версии Steam карточки игр имеют красивую анимацию. [image]

Я попытался их воссоздать, но работают они у меня странно:

```js
"use strict";

const card = document.querySelector('.card-box');

card.addEventListener('mousemove', rotate, { capture: true });
card.addEventListener('mouseout', rotateout, { capture: true });

function rotate(e) {
  this.style.transition = 'none';

  const rect = this.getBoundingClientRect(),
    cardW = rect.width,
    cardH = rect.height;

  let xFormula = e.clientX - (rect.left + cardW / 2),
    yFormula = e.clientY - (rect.top + cardH / 2);

  let resY = yFormula,
    resX = xFormula;

  // console.log(`${resX}, ${resY}`)

  this.style.transform = `rotateY(${resX}deg) rotateX(${resY}deg)`;
}

function rotateout(e) {
  this.style.transition = 'transform 0.2s linear';
  this.style.transform = 'rotateX(0)';
  this.style.transform = 'rotateY(0)';
}
```

```css
.card-box {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  perspective: 500px;
  }

.card {
  width: 150px;
  height: 175px;
  border: 3px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 200px auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-box">
  <div class="card">карта</div>
</div>
```

Вопрос: как сделать, чтобы карточки наклонялись так же, как в Steam.

<strike>Оправдание</strike>: плохо умею создавать элементы интерфейса подобной сложности.

---

```js
"use strict";

const cardBox = document.querySelector('.card-box'),
  card = document.querySelector('.card');

cardBox.addEventListener('mousemove', rotate, {
  capture: true
});
cardBox.addEventListener('mouseout', rotateout, {
  capture: true
});

function rotate(e) {
  const rect = this.getBoundingClientRect(),
    w = rect.width / 10,
    h = rect.height / 10,
    x = (e.clientX - w) / 2,
    y = (e.clientY - h) / 2;

  card.style.transform = `rotateY(${y}deg) rotateX(${x}deg)`;
}

function rotateout(e) {
  card.style.transform = 'rotateX(0) rotateY(0)';
}
```

```css
.card-box {
  perspective: 1000px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.card {
  transition: .1s linear;
  width: 150px;
  height: 175px;
  border: 3px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 200px auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-box">
  <div class="card">карта</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Если добавить родительский div и прописать на него `transform-style: preserve-3d; perspective: 500px;` то станет гораздо менее странно

Comment: @andreymal, спасибо, добавил в вопрос

Comment: А теперь если перевесить обработчики mousemove/mouseout с card на card-box, то станет меньше неадекватных скачков (потому что считать координаты по постоянно двигающемуся объекту это довольно сомнительная затея)

Comment: @andreymal, спасибо*2)

Comment: А теперь вы зачем-то стали менять трансформацию у card-box, тем самым лишив его смысла существования, ведь снова всё стало скакать

Comment: @andreymal, поправил

Comment: Не поправили, строчка `card.style.transform` по-прежнему пихает трансформацию в card-box

Comment: @andreymal, а как тогда? Она не будет наклоняться

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/wvKarLJ?editors=1100 так наверно ?

Comment: @Voprositel если пихать трансформации в card вместо card-box, то всё будет отлично наклоняться

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Делается это вот так

Большая работа на css в которой делаем перспективу а вот при наведении в зависимости от курсора меняем угол наклона

**Для адаптивности - достаточно просто изменить font с 200px на 20vw**

```js
document.getElementById('perspective').addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  var w = window.innerWidth / 2;
  var h = window.innerHeight / 2;
  var x = (e.pageX - w) / 10;
  var y = (e.pageY - h) / 10;
  document.getElementById('object').style.transform = 'rotateX(' + y + 'deg) rotateY(' + x + 'deg)';
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

html,
body,
#perspective {
  height: 100%;
}

#perspective {
  perspective: 1000px;
  /* center object */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#object {
  transition: 300ms ease-out;
  /* optional */
  background: #bbb;
  padding: 20px;
  /* example content */
  font: bold 20vw sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div id="perspective">
  <div id="object">3D</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Можно, пожалуйста, адаптивное решение. Я попытался сам сделать на основе вашего примера, но не получилось:(. Код попытки приложил к вопросу.

Comment: @Voprositel там в css видите font ?

Comment: я немного ошибся с определениями. Мой пример, который я приложил к вопросу написан в новом стандарте, там используется `getBoundingClientRect`, как сделать, чтобы он работал также?

Comment: @Voprositel не знаю - надо шарится - смотреть - у меня ни всегда есть время на это